# Firebase: Atributos en una clase POJO no persistibles

Tags: android, firebase

Tengo una clase que utilizo para añadir registros en mi BD Firebase con `setValue(empresa)`. La clase tiene 3 atributos, y todo funciona perfectamente.
Pero mi consulta es: ¿Se puede tener un atributo en la clase POJO pero que no se añada al registro de la BD al hacer un `setValue(empresa)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se puede, se hace con `@Exclude`. dejo un ejemplo en java porque no especificaste el lenguaje.

```
public class Empresa{

  public String nombre;
  public String OtroNombre;
  ...
  @Exclude
  public String dineroEnNegro;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes crear dos constructores para Empresa, uno con el valor que necesitas y otro con los que no

```
public class Empresa{

  private String nombre;
  private String OtroNombre;
  ...
  private String dineroEnNegro;

  //Constructor por defecto
  public Empresa(nombre,otroNombre,dineroEnNegro) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.OtroNombre = otroNombre;
  this.dineroEnNegro = dineroEnNegro;
 }

//Constructor con solo los valores que necesitas
 public Empresa(nombre,otroNombre) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.OtroNombre = otroNombre;
 }

}
```

Luego podes usar uno u otro para manejar tus datos

Luego lo podes usar de dos formas

```
Empresa empresa = new Empresa("Nombre","otroNombre","dineroEnNegro");
Empresa empresa2 = new Empresa("Nombre","otroNombre");
```

y podes mandar los datos a Firebase con cualquiera de los dos constructores

```
referencia.child("datos").setValue(empresa);
referencia.child("datos").setValue(empresa2);
```

PD: Recorda que los atributos de un POJO deben ser privados, ya que deben ser solo accedidos por el constructor y dicha clase Empresa, y no deberian ser visiles fuera de la clase, sino romperia el principio de encapsulacion